# REST multiple insert

Tags: json, rest, salesforce

I need to insert few rows into OpportunityLineItem table within single POST request
https://***.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem

Single insert works ok for me:
{"OpportunityId":"xxx","Quantity":1,"UnitPrice":100,"PricebookEntryId":"xxx"}

But it fails when I try to POST multiple records
{"records" : [{"OpportunityId":"xxx","Quantity":1,"UnitPrice":100,"PricebookEntryId":"xxx"},
{"OpportunityId":"xxx","Quantity":4,"UnitPrice":110,"PricebookEntryId":"xxx"}]}

Comment: Does the salesforce docs that that it should be possible to post more than 1?

Comment: they support up to 200 records per request via SOAP API. REST API is quite new and not documented well

Answer (score 4):

You can't insert multiple rows in a single call in the rest api, you need to use the bulk api.

Comment: Almost three years later, is this still true?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson: Fixed in Sommer '15 release. I found the solution in a [duplicate question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/75660/2555)

Answer (score 0):

**Summer '15 release** allows to combine different operations like insert, update, delete get on different objects types into one request. [Release note](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000214070&language=en_US)

I found it in a [duplicate question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/75660/2555).